# What is the most usable navigation mark up for screen readers?

Tags: navigation, screen-reader, markup

When we mark up navigation data for a website we have several options available, including using html lists, html5 nav tags or just plain divs and spans. We also have various options at the attribute level such as aria and microdata.

If we were creating navigation mark-up which was solely targeted at supporting the users of screen reader technology and we were concerned with making it as quick and uncomplicated as possible for our users to navigate our website, what would be the best choice of html mark-up tags and attributes?

Answer (score 2):

There are five "features" you can enable for screen reader users:

- (1) **Jump** to the navigation. (*I want to go somewhere else.*)
- (2) **Announce** that it’s for navigation. (*Where am I?*)
- (3) **Label** for the navigation. (*What is this navigation for?*)
- (4) **Read**/**navigate** its links. (*Where can I go?*)
- (5) **Count** its links. (*How long/complex is it?*)

(1) and (2) can be achieved by using HTML5’s [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/sections.html#the-nav-element). It makes it clear that it’s "a section with navigation links". And by default it comes with WAI-ARIAs [`navigation` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/dom.html#index-aria-navigation). So supporting screen readers can (1) announce that the user is currently inside the navigation and (2) allow the user to jump to navigation(s) from anywhere on the page.

(3) can be achieved by using a heading element (`h1`-`h2`) for this `nav` or by using WAI-ARIA’s [`aria-label` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/states_and_properties#aria-label). But note that labeling the navigation is not necessarily required/sensible (e.g., there is no label required if it’s the only navigation on the page).

(4) is usually the case by default, but some "clever" implementations might mess it up (e.g., using icon fonts with no meaninungful alternative text).

(5) can be achieved by using the [`ul` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element). Supporting screen readers can announce how many items the list has. On top of that, they might offer quick navigation for the list (jump to beginning/end). Bonus: using a list allows to specify sub-items in a machine (and thus screen reader) readable way.

So it could look like:

```
<nav>
  <!-- uncomment if appropriate: <h1>Navigation label</h1> -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/link-1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link-2">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```